# How do I override a Java KeyListener in a window?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, keylistener, focusable

So I am writing a simple fighting game in Java that includes both a title screen JPanel, as well as a Playspace JPanel. I have been experiencing some issues with getting the Playspace's KeyListener to work after adding the title screen. I have tried numerous other suggestions from other SO posts, and have seen none work so far. Below is my Playspace constructor, with the int mode being single or multiplayer, and app being the JFrame. It should be noted that both Title and Play screens are in the same frame.

```
/** Constructor, sets frame and arrays up **/
    public Playspace(int mode, Application app) {

        // Sets up JPanel
        super();

        // Application variables
        this.app = app;
        HEIGHT = app.getHeight();
        WIDTH = app.getWidth();
        setLayout(null);
        setLocation(0, 0);
        setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        backgroundColor = new Color(50, 50, 60);
        backgroundColor.brighter();
        setBackground(backgroundColor);
        setVisible(true);
        setFocusable(true);
        requestFocusInWindow();
        addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
            /** Keypress detection **/
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

                int i = 0;
                if (runnable[i]) {
                    // WASD Controls
                    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
                        players[i].setLeftPressed(true);
                        players[i].setDirection(-1);
                    }

                    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
                        players[i].setRightPressed(true);
                        players[i].setDirection(1);
                    }

                    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
                        players[i].setDownPressed(true);
                    }

                    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
                        players[i].setUpPressed(true);
                        players[i].setUpReleased(false);
                    }

                    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT && e.getKeyLocation() == KeyEvent.KEY_LOCATION_LEFT
                            && players[i].isShiftReleased()) {
                        players[i].setShiftPressed(true);
                        players[i].setShiftReleased(false);
                    }
                }

                i = 1;
                if (runnable[i]) {
                    // ULDR Controls
                    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
                        players[i].setLeftPressed(true);
                        players[i].setDirection(-1);
                    }

                    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
                        players[i].setRightPressed(true);
                        players[i].setDirection(1);
                    }

                    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
                        players[i].setDownPressed(true);
                    }

                    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
                        players[i].setUpPressed(true);
                        players[i].setUpReleased(false);
                    }

                    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT && e.getKeyLocation() == KeyEvent.KEY_LOCATION_RIGHT
                            && players[i].isShiftReleased()) {
                        players[i].setShiftPressed(true);
                        players[i].setShiftReleased(false);
                    }
                }
            }

            /** Key Release detection **/
            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

                if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_F11) {
                    developerMode = !developerMode;
                }

                int i = 0;
                // WASD Controls
                if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
                    players[i].setLeftPressed(false);
                }

                if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
                    players[i].setDownPressed(false);
                }

                if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
                    players[i].setRightPressed(false);
                }

                if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
                    players[i].setUpPressed(false);
                    players[i].setUpReleased(true);
                }
                if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT && e.getKeyLocation() == KeyEvent.KEY_LOCATION_LEFT) {
                    players[i].setShiftPressed(false);
                    players[i].setShiftReleased(true);
                }

                i = 1;
                // ULDR Controls
                if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
                    players[i].setUpPressed(false);
                    players[i].setUpReleased(true);
                }

                if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
                    players[i].setDownPressed(false);
                }

                if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
                    players[i].setLeftPressed(false);
                }

                if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
                    players[i].setRightPressed(false);
                }

                if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT && e.getKeyLocation() == KeyEvent.KEY_LOCATION_RIGHT) {
                    players[i].setShiftPressed(false);
                    players[i].setShiftReleased(true);
                }
            }

            /** We need this, but would rather forget it... **/
            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            }
        });
        setVisible(true);
```

**It continues from here, but this is the setup in its entirety

Thanks to all that can provide help

One more note, I have tried adding some print statements to the KeyListener, but to no avail, the listener is never called.

Comment: THE ISSUE HAS NOW BEEN RESOLVED!!! THANKS ALL FOR YOUR HELP!

Comment: *"THE ISSUE HAS NOW BEEN RESOLVED!!!"* 1) Don't **SHOUT** at us. We are not deaf. 2) Fix that stuck `!` key while you're at it. 3) Congrats on solving it. But without the solution in an answer below, this is useless to everyone else. Either add an answer below, or delete the question entirely, using the link below-left of the question above.

Comment: I should be able to post a fix with code today.